# How to import HTMX variable?

Tags: htmx

I am using HTMX attributes on some dynamically generated DOM elements. HTMX is not working, as stated in [the docs](https://htmx.org/docs/#3rd-party) unless you call `htmx.process()`.

When I tried to call this, I get - correctly - the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: htmx is not defined

Any idea how I can import this htmx variable? No idea how the example in the docs can work.

Thx!

Comment: When I "install" it [according to the documentation](https://htmx.org/docs/#installing), there's an `htmx` global created, which has the `process` function on it. How are you "installing" it?

Comment: I am using django-webpack-loader and there in the index.js is an `import htmx.org`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't use Django. Do you really mean `import htmx.org`? Not `import "htmx.org"`? In a JavaScript `import`, the module specifier has to be in quotes, so maybe that's not a JavaScript `import` statement? (If it is and you just forgot the quotes, my guess is you need `import htmx from "htmx.org";` or `import * as htmx from "htmx.org";` [probably the first one]).

Comment: Well, it's about Django in that you said you're using `django-webpack-loader` and loaders in Webpack handle imports. Did you try the options I suggested? When you use `import`, you usually *don't* get a global. (Half the point of modules is to avoid globals.) Edit: Ah, your comment disappeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The non-module version of `htmx.org` defines a global, but you're using modules (via `import`). Half the point of modules is to do away with globals, and so the module version of it won't create a global, it'll provide an export.

In a deleted comment you said the actual import is `import "htmx.org"` (not `import htmx.org` as in the comment that's still there). That being the case, you likely want one of these:

```js
// Importing the default export
import htmx from "htmx.org";
// Or importing the module namespace object
import * as htmx from "htmx.org";
// Or importing a named export, but looking at the file I doubt you want this one
import { htmx } from "htmx.org";
```

Most likely, you want the first one.

You'd do that in the module where you're doing the `htmx.process()` call.

Comment: Great, thanks! It seems to work! Unfortunately I don't manage to bring together the jquery datatables for which I need the `htmx.process()` and the import. In my template I cannot say import htmx.org because he wants something path-like but I don't have access to the source file because it's bundled with webpack... And in my js-file I can do the import but the jquery is not working for multiple reasons.

Comment: I'm glad that at least takes you a step further. Sorry not to  be able to help with the rest. :-)

Comment: This seems to be the answer in my custom JS file: `window.htmx = require('htmx.org');`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!!

Comment: If you like, you could update your answer for this case. If not, its ok as well.

Comment: @Ron - I'm glad that works, but creating a global from a module export like that isn't best practice. I suspect that with more specific knowledge of the tools you're using, it would be possible to do this without creating the global. Anyway, good luck with it! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! At the moment I'm super happy that it works but I'll keep it in mind! I'd never use a global in Python 

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML file, after including Htmx, listen for the load event.
E.g. to enable logging:

```js
<script>
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:load', function (evt) {
  htmx.logAll();
});
</script>
```